# Setting Timeout after one loop of Interval in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This one is hard one. I spent some days now to solve this issue but all the solutions I tried wasn't accurate.

The thing is that I'm trying to build 'typing text effect'. This should also handle change of the sentences, ie. the first sentence is typed, then it disappears and the other sentences is starting to be typed again, and so on, it goes in the loop. The issue here is that while the first sentence is finished I would like to leave my blinker for a while, for example for 2 sec. This seems to be a perfect place to use setTimeout but all of my trials were unfortunately wrong.

I would really appreciate if you could help me! Thank you

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../sass/main.scss';

class TypeAnimation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sec: 0,
            sec2: 0,
            currentSentence: 0,
            blinker: '|',
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.textInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(
                prevState => ({ 
                    sec: prevState.sec !== this.props.text[0].length ? prevState.sec + 1 : 0,
                    currentSentence: prevState.sec === this.props.text[0].length ?
                    prevState.currentSentence + 1 : prevState.currentSentence,
                })
            ); 
        }, 100);
    }


    render() {
        let otherSentences;
        const nextSentences = this.props.text; // here comes the array of few sentences
        const currentText = nextSentences[this.state.currentSentence];

        if (this.state.currentSentence !== nextSentences.length) {
            otherSentences = currentText.substr(0, this.state.sec);
        } else {
            clearInterval(this.textInterval);
            otherSentences = nextSentences[nextSentences.length - 1];
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>
                    {otherSentences}
                    <span className='blinker'> {this.state.blinker} </span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TypeAnimation;
```

Comment: have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame instead of timeout?

Comment: `setTimeout` could be inaccurate in terms of frequency of updating, so

Comment: Could be helpful http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/requestanimationframe.shtml

Comment: Thanks for that, the only think I need to figure out is how to setInterval using requestAnimationFrame ;)

Comment: @Barth by calling it recursively